# how to stop atribution to variable in for if

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

I'm a total newbie in programming - actually I'm learning `javaScript` and I have a problem with one task.

This is the code:

```js
let myFewNumbers = [1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5, 9];
let myIndex = 0;

for (i = 0; i < myFewNumbers.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < myFewNumbers.length; j++) {
    if (i != j && myFewNumbers[i] === myFewNumbers[j]) {
      myIndex = j;
      break;
    }
  }
}
console.log(myIndex);
```

I don't know how to stop `atribution` to variable because when `if` is true then changes variable `myIndex` to `j` but I want to know the *first* number that repeats, not the *last* one. I know that rest of my code is ok, and I don't want to change anything in this, but I think there is something missing in the `if` line.

Comment: You need a flag on the outer for-loop.

Comment: Your `break` only breaks the inner loop.

Comment: What is the desired outcome?

Comment: i'm looking for first number that repeats in table, so myIndex should show me "1" because first number that repeats is 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a flag `foundIndex` to the outer-loop's conditional.

That way, when the break is reached in the inner-loop, the outer loop exits immediately.

**Update:** It looks like you want the first index of the first duplicate. I have updated the logic to reflect this.

You need to:

1. add this to your conditional: `j > i`
2. store and sort every index to get the min index

```js
let myFewNumbers = [1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5, 9];
let myIndex = 0;
let foundIndicies = [];

for (i = 0; i < myFewNumbers.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < myFewNumbers.length; j++) {
    if (j > i && i != j && myFewNumbers[i] === myFewNumbers[j]) {
      myIndex = j;
      foundIndicies.push(j);
    }
  }
}
console.log(Math.min.apply(Math, foundIndicies)); // 4
```

#### A functional approach

An easier design pattern would be to wrap this in a function and exit immediately, upon locating the duplicate value.

Your final conditional reads as follows, in this order:

```js
if (j < minIndex && i !== j && j > i && arr[i] === arr[j])
```

```js
// The number 4 is the first duplicate to appear.
console.log(findFirstDuplicateIndex( [1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5, 9] )); // Index: 4 
console.log(findFirstDuplicate(      [1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5, 9] )); // Value: 4 

// With the duplicate 4 removed, 1 is now the first duplicate.
console.log(findFirstDuplicateIndex( [1, 4, 3, 2, 5, 1, 2, 5, 9]    )); // Index: 5 
console.log(findFirstDuplicate(      [1, 4, 3, 2, 5, 1, 2, 5, 9]    )); // Value: 1

function findFirstDuplicate(arr) {
  let index = findFirstDuplicateIndex(arr);
  return index > -1 ? arr[index] : null;
}

function findFirstDuplicateIndex(arr) {
  let minIndex = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (j < minIndex && i !== j && j > i && arr[i] === arr[j]) {
        minIndex = j;
      }
    }
  }
  return minIndex !== Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER ? minIndex : -1;
}
```

Comment: i'm looking for first number that repeats in table, so myIndex should show me "1" because first number that repeats is 4. In your proposition there is 6

Comment: @hvma411 Updated one last time, cleaned-up the logic in the functional example.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to break if you add another condition to your loops. Here's an example:

```js
let myFewNumbers = [1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5, 9];
let myIndex = -1;

for (i = 0; i < myFewNumbers.length && myIndex < 0; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < myFewNumbers.length && myIndex < 0; j++) {
    if (i != j && myFewNumbers[i] === myFewNumbers[j]) {
      myIndex = j;
    }
  }
}
console.log(myIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of possible answers, but one that's useful an interesting is labeled loops:

```
fast:
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        if (j === 2)
            break fast;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can **break more than 1 loop** with label:

```
let myFewNumbers = [1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5, 9];
let myIndex = 0;

outer_loop:
for (i = 0; i < myFewNumbers.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < myFewNumbers.length; j++) {
        if (i != j && myFewNumbers[i] === myFewNumbers[j]) {
            myIndex = j;
            break outer_loop;
        }
    }
}

console.log(myIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have two loops but you only `break;` (which stops execution of the loop) in the second loop:

```
let myFewNumbers = [1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5, 9];
let myIndex = 0;
let foundDuplicate = false;

for (i = 0; i < myFewNumbers.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < myFewNumbers.length; j++) {
    if (i != j && myFewNumbers[i] === myFewNumbers[j]) {
      myIndex = j;
      foundDuplicate = true
      break;
    }
  }
  if(foundDuplicate )break;
}
console.log(myIndex);
```

not too sure why you have two loops and not one but this should help :)

Comment: I think your 'if(foundDuplicate )break;` needs to be one line down.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that although your break from the inner loop, the outer loop continues the iteration.

Don't assign a number to `myIndex` and in the outer loop (`i`) iterate as long as `myIndex` is `undefined`.

Notes:

1. You can stop looping when when `i` is `length - 1`, since the last number can't be a duplicate of itself.
2. You can init j as `i + 1`, and then you can remove the condition `i != k`, since you already covered all cases when `j` is less or equal `i`.

```js
let myFewNumbers = [1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5, 9];
let myIndex;

for (i = 0; i < myFewNumbers.length - 1 && myIndex === undefined; i++) {
  for (j = i + 1; j < myFewNumbers.length; j++) {
    if (myFewNumbers[i] === myFewNumbers[j]) {
      myIndex = i;
      break;
    }
  }
}
console.log(myIndex);
```

A better option would be to wrap the loops in a function, and return when the `if` condition is `true`:

```js
const myFewNumbers = [1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5, 9];

const fn = arr => {
  for (i = 0; i < myFewNumbers.length - 1; i++) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < myFewNumbers.length; j++) {
      if (myFewNumbers[i] === myFewNumbers[j]) {
        return i;
      }
    }
  }
};

const myIndex = fn(myFewNumbers);

console.log(myIndex);
```

Comment: i'm looking for first number that repeats in table, so myIndex should show me "1" because first number that repeats is 4. In your proposition there is 6

Comment: The answer should be 0 because 1 is a duplicate as well. You should use `i` as the result. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your codes but it is not that i'm looking for. I want to know the first number that repeats, so if my table is "const myFewNumbers = [1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5, 9];" the first number that repeats is 4, so "myIndex" should show me "1".